# How to evaluate a statistical test for fairness of a coin?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, self-study

I suspect that a given coin is not fair, i.e that the probability of heads is not $\frac{1}{2}$. My question is not how we can prove the unfairness, but if we derive a test to check the fairness, How we can evaluate the test?

Say, for $n$ number of tosses, the coin always turned up heads. What is the minimal number  $n$ in order to reject the fairness hypothesis at significance level of 1%?

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of such a hypothesis test is that, if the coin were fair, what is the probability of observing $n$ heads out of $n$ tosses, or $n$ tails out of $n$ tosses?  If this probability is sufficiently small--i.e., smaller than the selected significance level--then you would conclude that the evidence suggests that the coin is not fair, because if it were, the chance of having observed the result you did is too small.

So, the probability that a fair coin would show $n$ heads or $n$ tails in $n$ tosses is simply $1/2^{n-1}$; that is to say, if $X$ is the random variable indicating the number of heads obtained in $n$ tosses, then $$\Pr[(X = 0) \vee (X = n) \mid H_0 : p = 0.5] = (0.5)^{n-1}.$$  Consequently, you wish to find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that this probability is less than $0.01$.  This should be straightforward.